# Change Value in Cell after using it

Tags: excel

i have the following Problem. 
I want to use a Value in a cell and i want to set it to a specific value after using this value.

```
Example 
[Inventory] 
[      100]

[Sold][Turnover]
[  90][  =90*10]
```

After that the Value of Inventory should be 10 but the cells of Sold and Turnover shouldnt change.

PS: I think a makro is needed but i dont habe expierince in VBA

Thanks

Comment: You could have a cell with initial inventory, then as you go down each row with either sales or inputs and keep the running total that way...

Answer (score 0):

So, without any idea of what you have and your layout, this is something you could consider. Add to it as you wish - a column for dates, client name etc etc

[image]

It does not work exactly as you stated, but does keep track as you intended...